# Why is the TableColumn containing the measure names disappearing after I adjust the slider in bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, bokeh

I have created DataTable based on the output of .describe() with bokeh that updates when I adjust the slider. All of the other columns in the data table seem to be updating correctly, however the first column containing the measure names disappears upon callback. That is, the title is still there, however the field is blank. How do I fix this so that the measure column doesn't go blank?

my code is as follows:

```
def modify_table(doc):

    my_cols = ['Tuition Per Student', 'Students', 'Total Tuition', 'Other Revenue', 'Total Revenue', 'Expense', 'Margin']

    source = ColumnDataSource(ed_montecarlo(department_data, 'Education and Early Childhood', num=1000, expense_var=.3)[my_cols]. \
                          describe().iloc[1:,].round(2))

    columns = [TableColumn(field='index', title='Measure'), 
               TableColumn(field='Tuition Per Student', title='Tuition Per Student'),
               TableColumn(field='Students', title='Number of Students'),
               TableColumn(field='Total Tuition', title='Total Tuition'),
               TableColumn(field='Other Revenue', title='Other Revenue'),
               TableColumn(field='Total Revenue', title='Total Revenue'),
               TableColumn(field='Expense', title='Total Expense'),
               TableColumn(field='Margin', title='Margin')]

    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, index_position=None, width=700)

    def callback(attr, old, new):
        other_sims = ed_montecarlo(department_data, 'Education and Early Childhood', num=iter_slider.value, expense_var=.3)[my_cols]
        other_sims_table = other_sims.describe().iloc[1:,].round(2)

        source.data = {
            'Measure'                : list(other_sims_table.index),
            'Tuition Per Student'    : list(other_sims_table['Tuition Per Student']),
            'Students'               : list(other_sims_table['Students']),
            'Total Tuition'          : list(other_sims_table['Total Tuition']),
            'Other Revenue'          : list(other_sims_table['Other Revenue']),
            'Total Revenue'          : list(other_sims_table['Total Revenue']),
            'Expense'                : list(other_sims_table['Expense']),
            'Margin'                 : list(other_sims_table['Margin']),

    }

    iter_slider = Slider(start=100, end=5000, step=100, value=1000, title='Number of Iterations')
    iter_slider.on_change('value', callback) 
    widg = widgetbox(iter_slider)

    doc.add_root(column(widg, data_table))

show(modify_table)
```

note that ed_montecarlo is a function that I have written that returns a dataframe output of the different iterations of a montecarlo simulation. Everything appears to be working except for this one column.

Here is the output before I adjust the slider:
[image: Before Adjusting Slider]

And here is the output after:
[image]

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. The issue was with this block:

```
    source.data = {
        'Measure'                : list(other_sims_table.index),
        'Tuition Per Student'    : list(other_sims_table['Tuition Per Student']),
        'Students'               : list(other_sims_table['Students']),
        'Total Tuition'          : list(other_sims_table['Total Tuition']),
        'Other Revenue'          : list(other_sims_table['Other Revenue']),
        'Total Revenue'          : list(other_sims_table['Total Revenue']),
        'Expense'                : list(other_sims_table['Expense']),
        'Margin'                 : list(other_sims_table['Margin']),

}
```

I should have instead changed 'Measure' to be 'index', as a result I was creating a new column called 'Measure' that was then not being referenced in the main function. The correct code would be:

```
    source.data = {
        'index'                  : list(other_sims_table.index),
        'Tuition Per Student'    : list(other_sims_table['Tuition Per Student']),
        'Students'               : list(other_sims_table['Students']),
        'Total Tuition'          : list(other_sims_table['Total Tuition']),
        'Other Revenue'          : list(other_sims_table['Other Revenue']),
        'Total Revenue'          : list(other_sims_table['Total Revenue']),
        'Expense'                : list(other_sims_table['Expense']),
        'Margin'                 : list(other_sims_table['Margin']),

}
```